# Jax/Flax (very) slow RNN-forward-pass compared to pyTorch?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, jax

I recently implemented a two-layer GRU network in Jax and was disappointed by its performance (it was unusable).

##### So, i tried a little speed comparison with Pytorch.

###### Minimal working example

This is my minimal working example and the output was created on Google Colab with GPU-runtime. [notebook in colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aUc2w1N8Xth1qEU7X9fmDyFHBv78R7LY?usp=sharing)

```py
import flax.linen as jnn 
import jax
import torch
import torch.nn as tnn
import numpy as np 
import jax.numpy as jnp

def keyGen(seed):
    key1 = jax.random.PRNGKey(seed)
    while True:
        key1, key2 = jax.random.split(key1)
        yield key2
key = keyGen(1)

hidden_size=200
seq_length = 1000
in_features = 6
out_features = 4
batch_size = 8

class RNN_jax(jnn.Module):

    @jnn.compact
    def __call__(self, x, carry_gru1, carry_gru2):
        carry_gru1, x = jnn.GRUCell()(carry_gru1, x)
        carry_gru2, x = jnn.GRUCell()(carry_gru2, x)
        x = jnn.Dense(4)(x)
        x = x/jnp.linalg.norm(x)
        return x, carry_gru1, carry_gru2

class RNN_torch(tnn.Module):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, hidden_size, in_features, out_features):
        super().__init__()

        self.gru = tnn.GRU(
            input_size=in_features, 
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            num_layers=2
            )
        
        self.dense = tnn.Linear(hidden_size, out_features)

        self.init_carry = torch.zeros((2, batch_size, hidden_size))

    def forward(self, X):
        X, final_carry = self.gru(X, self.init_carry)
        X = self.dense(X)
        return X/X.norm(dim=-1).unsqueeze(-1).repeat((1, 1, 4))

rnn_jax = RNN_jax()
rnn_torch = RNN_torch(batch_size, hidden_size, in_features, out_features)

Xj = jax.random.normal(next(key), (seq_length, batch_size, in_features))
Yj = jax.random.normal(next(key), (seq_length, batch_size, out_features))
Xt = torch.from_numpy(np.array(Xj))
Yt = torch.from_numpy(np.array(Yj))

initial_carry_gru1 = jnp.zeros((batch_size, hidden_size))
initial_carry_gru2 = jnp.zeros((batch_size, hidden_size))

params = rnn_jax.init(next(key), Xj[0], initial_carry_gru1, initial_carry_gru2)

def forward(params, X):
    
    carry_gru1, carry_gru2 = initial_carry_gru1, initial_carry_gru2

    Yhat = []
    for x in X: # x.shape = (batch_size, in_features)
        yhat, carry_gru1, carry_gru2 = rnn_jax.apply(params, x, carry_gru1, carry_gru2)
        Yhat.append(yhat) # y.shape = (batch_size, out_features)

    #return jnp.concatenate(Y, axis=0)

jitted_forward = jax.jit(forward)
```

###### Results

```py
# uncompiled jax version
%time forward(params, Xj)
```

`CPU times: user 7min 17s, sys: 8.18 s, total: 7min 25s Wall time: 7min 17s`

```py
# time for compiling
%time jitted_forward(params, Xj)
```

`CPU times: user 8min 9s, sys: 4.46 s, total: 8min 13s Wall time: 8min 12s`

```py
# compiled jax version
%timeit jitted_forward(params, Xj)
```

`The slowest run took 204.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 10000 loops, best of 5: 115 µs per loop`

```py
# torch version
%timeit lambda: rnn_torch(Xt)
```

`10000000 loops, best of 5: 65.7 ns per loop`

###### Questions

Why is my Jax-implementation so slow? What am i doing wrong?

Also, why is compiling taking so long? The sequence is not that long..

Thank you :)

Comment: Your example has some undefined variables, namely `nn` and `n_hidden`

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the JAX code compiles slowly is that during JIT compilation JAX unrolls loops. So in terms of XLA compilation, your function is actually very large: you call `rnn_jax.apply()` 1000 times, and compilation times tend to be roughly quadratic in the number of statements.

By contrast, your pytorch function uses no Python loops, and so under the hood it is relying on vectorized operations that run much faster.

Any time you use a `for` loop over data in Python, a good bet is that your code will be slow: this is true whether you're using JAX, torch, numpy, pandas, etc. I'd suggest finding an approach to the problem in JAX that relies on vectorized operations rather than relying on slow Python looping.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would you vectorize a RNN. The sequence dimension depends on each previous computation. I am not sure how PyTorch does it, but it has a built-in sequence dimension, hence i don't need to loop.

Comment: In JAX I think [`fori_loop`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.fori_loop.html) is probably your best bet. But it would be worth checking the flax examples to see how this is typically done.

Comment: Oh wow. I think i figured it out. Any additional dimension in X that you give rnn_jax.apply(X) will somehow get reduced as if it were a sequence dimension. So just like in pyTorch. I don't know how one is supposed to know that from the documentation. Maybe i redo the speed runs this afternoon and update the results if you are curious.